# Attempting to "importDump.php" in mediawiki on bitnami instance on Google Cloud, getting error "failed to open stream..."

Tags: mediawiki, bitnami

Followed the 2x options for commands at:  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps#Using_importDump.php,_if_you_have_shell_access

In both instances, getting a 'failed to open stream' error.

I have chmod 777 for folder and file.  (Thinking it may be permission error)

I have moved the file to import right into the maintenance folder (some postings suggesting PHP needs to be able to find the file, so think putting it there will help)...

on command:

"root@bitnami-mediawiki-___:/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/maintenance# php importDump.php --co
nf ../LocalSettings.php /FILENAME.xml"

I see error:

"PHP Warning:  fopen(/FILENAME.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/bitnam
i/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/maintenance/importDump.php on line 267
PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/
htdocs/includes/import/ImportStreamSource.php on line 41
PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki
/htdocs/includes/import/ImportStreamSource.php on line 48
PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/
htdocs/includes/import/ImportStreamSource.php on line 41
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read(): uploadsource://9115d0bbe5ae974e1fe2d411e035aeaa:1: parser error : Ext
ra content at the end of the document in /opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/includes/import/WikiImport
er.php on line 551
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read():  in /opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/includes/import/WikiImporter.p
hp on line 551
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read(): ^ in /opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/includes/import/WikiImporter.
php on line 551
Set $wgShowExceptionDetails = true; in LocalSettings.php to show detailed debugging information."

I'm not clear what the error means and how to grant access to the file...  Newb to BASH and servers.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the path of the FILENAME.xml file is wrong. Note that you have a `/` at the beginning of `FILENAME.xml`, so it will look at the root of the filesystem. If the file is in the same folder, then use `./FILENAME.xml`

Comment: Solved thanks!  In future, if the file were in a different folder, what would be the correct way to specify the path to the file name?  I'd like to understand the syntax better...